# NativeScript Angular - Get X and Y on tap event

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm doing a Nativescript-Angular-App and i have a problem.

The user has to click on the right position on a picture.

I don't understand how to get the coordinates of a simple tap.

I can get the coordinate with the touch gesture (TouchGestureEventData) but it provides a stream of informations. I just want one data.

- GestureEventData hasn't GetX() method.
- TouchGestureEventData has GetX() method but I want only the first touch.

I have tried with touch:

```
public onTouch(args: TouchGestureEventData) {
     console.log(args.getActivePointers()[0].getX());
}
```

But i get too many data (every movement).

Is there a way to get the coordinate just with a simple tap?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to get a single touch event. what you can do is check if event action is a `down` action or alternatively `up` action. for example the below code will just get you the X and Y coordinates of the touch-down event and will only happen once for each touch event.

```
public onTouch(e: TouchGestureEventData) {
    if (e && e.action === 'down') {
        this.xCoord = e.getX();
        this.yCoord = e.getY();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's working, thanks!
I had found a hack (Add directly on the html invisible element with tap method) but this solution better.

Answer (score 4):

Been researching this issue, and found a way for the tap event in iOS:

```
onTap(e) {
    const loc = e.ios.locationInView(e.object.ios);
    console.log("(x,y) in dp: " + loc.x + "," + loc.y);
}
```

I found that `e.ios` is the native object representation of that tap event, and tried to see what I can do with it, so I used Chrome DevTools, and started typing `e.ios.location`, and got the `locationInView()` autocomplete. I then searched for it in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitouch/1618116-locationinview?language=objc) and found that the function gets a `UIView` as an argument. So I tried `e.ios.locationInView(e.object);` and got an exception, so I remembered `UIView` is the iOS representation of nativescript's `View` class, so I tried `e.ios.locationInView(e.object.ios);` and got the `CGPoint` representing the tap coordinates in the view. 
It is important to note that `loc.x` and `loc.y` are in `dp` units.

For Android it's a lot simpler:

```
onTap(e) {
    const x = e.android.getX();
    const y = e.android.getY();
    console.log("(x,y) in pixels: " + x + "," + y);
}
```

Important to note that in this case the coordinates are in `pixel` units, so in order to convert it to `dp`, you would first have to `import { screen } from "platform";` where your imports are,  and then in order to get the x coordinate in `dp`, you would:
 
`e.android.getX() / screen.mainScreen.scale`

Comment: Also if you use TypeScript `e` should be of type `TouchGestureEventData` not `EventData`.